# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class when using firebase library

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, push-notification

When app deploy on play store its getting crashes with this error. Many times reported this error on crashlytics. How I can resolve I am using kotlin for our application.Also integrated firebse analytics for tracking each screen of the app and its performance.

[image: Please find screenshot]

***My  build.gradle***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {

    signingConfigs {
        config {
            storeFile file('D:\\Android Production\\Key Store\\keyTool\\allindiaitr.jks')
            storePassword '12345678'
            keyAlias = 'asasasasas'
            keyPassword '12345678'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId "dell.com.allindiaitr"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 61
        versionName "7.9"
        multiDexEnabled true
        resConfigs "en", "US"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

//    lintOptions {
//        checkReleaseBuilds false
//        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
//        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
//        abortOnError false
//    }


}

//configurations.all {
//    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
//        def requested = details.requested
//        if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
//            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
//                details.useVersion "26.+"
//            }
//        }
//    }
//}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    // (Recommended) Add Analytics
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'

    // Add dependency
//    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'


//    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation('com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.3.3') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'

//    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.2'
//    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.2'
//    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:16.0.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.11.0'
    implementation 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2'
    implementation project(':filepicker')

    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    //SMS User Consent API

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.1.0"

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```